# Setting environment vars in a Vertex AI jupyter notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-vertex-ai, vertex, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

This may sound simple, but its giving me a headache.
I want to set some environment vars on about 10 Vertex AI Instances for whoever logs on.

I have set a script to do this however it just doesn't seem to work.
Script looks something like this

```
#! /bin/bash

export API_KEY="some value"
```

It is in a GCS storage bucket and the `--post-startup-script` is set to that location of the script.

When the notebook starts up, nothing is put into the environment.

I have got this working on normal VMs using the `startup-script` below to write into `/etc/environment` however this doesn't work with notebooks.

```
        cat <<'EOF' >> env.sh
        #! /bin/bash

        testenv='TESTKEY="somevalue"
        TESTKEY2="thisisatestvalue'
        echo "$testenv" > /etc/environment

        EOF
```

Has anyone got this successfully working ?

I have also tried executing the shell script directly on the box, which just returns a permission denied.

Comment: Is this User Managed Notebooks, Google Managed or Workbench instances?